# Run shell script file inside docker file

Tags: bash, docker, shell, dockerfile

I have created a Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update --no-cache && apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash && apk add curl
COPY test-start.sh ./test-start.sh
RUN chmod +x ./test-start.sh
RUN sh ./test-start.sh
```

And I have created the test-start.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
code=$(curl https://someendpoint)

if [ $code == "200" ]
then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```

What I want to do is execute this shell script while creating the docker image and if get 200 response then continue building the image else stop building the image and throw error.
Now when I am trying to build the docker image I am getting an error

```
[+] Building 10.9s (10/10) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.dev                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.18kB                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                   1.9s
 => [auth] library/alpine:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:69665d02cb32192e52e07644d76bc6f25abeb5410edc1c7a81a10ba3f0e  0.0s
 => [2/5] RUN apk update --no-cache && apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash && apk add curl                           6.0s
 => [3/5] COPY test-start.sh ./test-start.sh                                                                       0.2s
 => [4/5] RUN chmod +x ./test-start.sh                                                                             0.7s
 => ERROR [5/5] RUN sh ./test-start.sh                                                                             1.9s
------
 > [5/5] RUN sh ./test-start.sh:
#10 0.790   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
#10 0.790                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     5  100     5    0     0      4      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--     4
: not found/test-start.sh: line 3:
#10 1.810 ./test-start.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected "fi" (expecting "then")
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c sh ./test-start.sh]: exit code: 2
```

I don't get what the error is and how it is to be resolved.

Also please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here as I am new to this and learning how this is to be done.

Thank You!

Comment: if you really run `curl` that way, it won't return the code, but the whole retrieved resource. On top of that, your condition `[ $code == "200" ]`  does not double-quote the variable, so most likely your comparison will be some garbage like `[ one two three whatever == "200" ]`. The correct way to get the HTTP code out of `curl` is `curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://...`

Comment: I would say, that, you're using an image, where curl is not installed. Try to execute `which curl` to see, if it's available or not.
On the other hand, most of commands are writing their exit codes into `$?` not into `stdout`.

Comment: Thanks @cornuz made the following changes now I am getting the http_status code.

Comment: @Andy I have install curl using apk add curl command in dockerfile. And my understanding of exit 0 and exit 1 is that it indicates if script ran successfully or terminated due to some error. I don't know how to know if exit 0 or exit 1 was fired in script from dockerfile.

Comment: @Andy `curl` was already installed, as you can see by the output `% Received`.

Comment: `: not found` often means your script is incorrectly using DOS-style line endings.  Is there some possibility this could be the case (are you working from a Windows host)?

Comment: (Also note that [curl](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) normally produces exit code 0 on success; you could probably just `RUN curl ...` without the script and get the behavior you want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`syntax error: unexpected "fi" (expecting "then")` seems strange. Even the unquoted `$code` shouldn't result in such an error.

Please check your script for Windows line endings (e.g. using `file test-start.sh`). If needed, convert your file to Linux line endings (e.g. using `dos2unix test-start.sh`).

After that, you may get another error, e.g. `[: too many arguments`. If that is the case, have a look at [Cornuz' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75572951/run-shell-script-file-inside-docker-file#comment133331107_75572951).
The variable `code` does not contain the http status, but curl's stdout which is the http body (e.g. `<HTML>...</HTML>` if you are querying a website). First, quote your variable; then tell `curl` to output only the http status code using `curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://...`.

By the way: `if [ ... ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi` is a bit redundant. You can just use the `[ ... ]`.

```
#!/bin/bash
code=$(curl curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://...)
[[ "$code" = "200" ]]
```